# MultiValueDictKeyError in Django when using ajax POST

Tags: ajax, django

I am using ajax post but get MultiValueDictKeyError. It is a shopping cart which I can add product to by click this item.

models.py

```
   class Product(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
        description = models.TextField()
        image_url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2)
   class LineItem(models.Model):
         product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
         unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2)
         quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id',)
class LineItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = LineItem
        fields = ('product', 'unit_price', 'quantity')
```

views.py

```
class RESTforCart(APIView):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    lists=request.session['cart'].items 
    serializer = LineItemSerializer(lists,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
def post(self, request, format=None):
    id=request.data["product"]["id"]
    product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    cart = request.session['cart']
    cart.add_product(product)
    request.session['cart'] = cart
    lists=request.session['cart'].items 
    serializer = LineItemSerializer(lists,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
(r'^API/cart/items/$', RESTforCart.as_view()),
```

My browsable API works well:
[Please click to see my browsable API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPrCu.png)

submit content is
{
        "product": {
            "id": 1
        },
        "unit_price": "12.00",
        "quantity": 2
 }

But when I using

```
$.post("/depotapp/API/cart/items/", { product: {  id: 1 , },  unit_price: "12.00",  quantity: 18, },function(data){ console.log(data);});
```

in my js file, get MultiValueDictKeyError at /depotapp/API/cart/items/
"'product'"
[please click to review error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrfdI.png)

Answer (score 0):

fix it in views.py

```
id=request.data["product[id]"]
```